How to trace debug logs in rabbitmq rabbitmq_tracing plugin
Using RabbitMQ 3.13.3 on a docker container setup with (based on https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/logging#log-exchange):
log.exchange = true
log.exchange.level = debug

and executed like this:
sudo docker run -d --name rabbitmq_mqtt -p 5672:5672 -p 15672:15672 -p 1883:1883 -v /etc/rabbitmq/conf/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf rabbitmq:3-management 

While learning I am experimenting with enabling the rabbitmq debug server logs to be stored within a separate file accessible by admin on the debug.log.
However, whatever I try, the debug log remains empty.

My exchanges:

My queue:

I verified that the tracing plugin works by being able to listen to an mqtt publisher and tracing the messages. When I try to trace messages that are clearly delivered to the queue, nothing is happening. I am wondering whether I should flush the messages from the queue?

The messages seem to be gathered in the queue, but need to be acknowledged for the tracing plugin to pick them up.

